# Why are my Timemachine snapshots being deleted almost immediately?

Tags: backup, time-machine, big-sur

I am on Big Sur and realise that Timemachine is not keeping local snapshots anymore. I have already tried turning automatic backups off/on in Timemachine.

I created a few manually and within a few minutes they were all deleted. There is more than 12GB of free space on my drive (this has not been a problem before).
[image: Snapshots disappearing]

Can anyone explain this and help me get the snapshots created again?
Thank you.

Comment: 12 GB is not much, but the log should tell you why it's thinning, e.g. ... `log show --predicate 'subsystem == "com.apple.TimeMachine"' --info --last 12h`

Comment: That's very useful to see. Thanks. There does seem to be a space problem, although the 10-12GB seemed to be sufficient in the past to keep some snapshots. However, now I see that Big Sur insists on keeping two large snapshots permanently, in addition to maybe one other snapshot:     "com.apple.TimeMachine.2022-04-24-205231.local",
"com.apple.os.update-64982378097932DDD27F7D55026F4C918109335A2FD320C0FE36D84CAFEDC8E1",
"com.apple.os.update-MSUPrepareUpdate"

Comment: "com.apple.os.update-..." is the snapshot Big Sur starts up from, instead of the system volume.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. I will just have to try to clear some space on my hard drive, if I want to have a few snapshots of recent changes.

Comment: I free-up some space. But, I just noticed that after the recent Mac OS update, the files "com.apple.os.update-64982378097932DDD27F7D55026F4C918109335A2FD320C0FE36D84CAFEDC8E1", "com.apple.os.update-MSUPrepareUpdate" have disappeared again. Strange.

Comment: Maybe it's just hidden again (the first one).  `diskutil list` should still show you the snapshot, Big Sur starts up from (also `mount` should show the disk's sub-slice, e.g. "disk1s2s1")

Comment: Yep - you are right. Thanks for the clarification.